# Cannot access Synology File Server from VPN using pfSense

Tags: vpn, nas, pfsense, synology-diskstation

OK, here is the situation:  I have a Synology file-server/NAS on my home network, watched over by pfSense (router/firewall).  I am trying to set up a VPN going through pfSense so that I can connect to my home network and access shared folders on my NAS just as if I were at home.

I finally was able to set up the VPN, using OpenVPN, and use a test laptop running Windows 11 to connect successfully. I've added the general settings for the client below:

```
dev tap
persist-tun
persist-key
data-ciphers *relevant ciphers used*
data-ciphers-fallback *relevant fallback ciphers*
auth *authorization cipher*
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote *vpn-address* *port* udp4
nobind
auth-user-pass
ca *certificate info*
tls-auth *key*
remote-cert-tls server
explicit-exit-notify
```

For the life of me, I cannot:

1. *Make my NAS appear in Windows File Explorer under the "Network" section*.  In the past, whenever I clicked on "Network" in File Explorer, any network devices like my NAS would show up: I could then click on that icon, put in my user credentials for the NAS, and a list of available shared folders would show up for me to access (double-clicking on one of those folders would automatically "map" it in Explorer).  For some reason, I can no longer see my NAS device in the "Network" area of File Explorer.
2. *Manually map the shared folders to a network drive in File Explorer.*  Even if the above doesn't happen, I've generally been able to click on "Map Network Drive" in order to explicitly add the shared folder on my NAS.  That's not working either:  Windows reports that it can't find that server name.

Here's the kicker:  *when I ping the NAS' IP address from the laptop, it's reachable*: I get quick response times, with no dropped packets.

I've checked multiple settings/solutions:

- MOST RECENT:  Based on comments and answers I've received here, I've come to realize that I needed to put configure my VPN as a TAP connection, and setup a bridge between the VPN and my LAN in pfSense.  I've done all of these, but the situation has not changed.
- The network is configured as a private network in Windows.
- I've done my best to review pfSense's firewall settings, and even
  made changes to explicitly allow the laptop's assigned IP to access
  the firewall.
- Originally I enabled the SMB 1.0 protocol in Windows, as one web post advised, but I've since disabled it on the advice of others here.
- I've ensured NetBIOS over TCP/IP is checked in Windows' Network Adapter Advanced Settings.
- I've ensured Function Discovery Services, SSDP Discovery, and UPnP
  Device Host Services in Windows Services are enabled and set to run
  automatically.

*What am I missing?*  THANKS for all of your suggestions and input!

Comment: "_I've ensured that the SMB 1.0 protocol in Windows is enabled (even though I thought users were supposed to avoid that protocol now)._" **Immediately disable and uninstall SMBv1** via `OptionalFeatures`! SMBv1 shoud _never_ be enabled, as it's been actively exploited daily for several years _(all OSes have supported SMBv2+ since ~2010, if not earlier)_. What type of VPN did you configure _(WireGuard or OpenVPN are the recommended options, in that order, as IPSec/HTML5 VPNs can't match the throughput of WireGuard or OpenVPN)_;  please edit your question to include the VPN configs.

Comment: Edited question to include requested information...thanks for the input, @JW0914.

Answer (score 2):

> Make my NAS appear in Windows File Explorer under the "Network" section. In the past, whenever I clicked on "Network" in File Explorer, any network devices like my NAS would show up: I could then click on that icon, put in my user credentials for the NAS, and a list of available shared folders would show up for me to access (double-clicking on one of those folders would automatically "map" it in Explorer). For some reason, I can no longer see my NAS device in the "Network" area of File Explorer.

Network discovery only works within the same broadcast domain, and typically VPNs are *not* directly attached to your Ethernet at all. (Even when they're sharing the same IP subnet number, that's usually done with some proxy-ARP magic; an IPsec VPN can't even handle broadcasts in the first place.) The most common mechanisms are WS-Discovery (used in Windows for SMB2), NetBIOS (SMB1-only), and mDNS (which Windows doesn't *yet* use for SMB).

For discovery to work, you'd need a "layer 2" VPN protocol (such as OpenVPN in *tap* mode specifically), making sure the VPN interface (e.g. tap0) on the server is bridged to the Ethernet LAN interface. But there's a lot of gotchas in doing so, and I really would not bother. Just make a direct shortcut to the network share's UNC address.

> Manually map the shared folders to a network drive in File Explorer. Even if the above doesn't happen, I've generally been able to click on "Map Network Drive" in order to explicitly add the shared folder on my NAS. That's not working either: Windows reports that it can't find that server name.

Depending on how your network is set up, "finding the server name" might rely on the same discovery protocols as above. (Not quite the same, but very close, and they have the same properties.) Your NAS might be advertising its name through LLMNR or mDNS or NetBIOS, all of which use either IP multicast or IPv4 broadcast and are limited to a single subnet, single broadcast domain.

Over a VPN, you'll need to set up a *DNS* server with some kind of internal domain that'll contain the server names you want to access. I *would* recommend doing so, but only as a second step after making sure access *by IP address* is working.

(If you cannot reach the server by its IP address, assigning names won't help with that at all.)

Comment: [TAP](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/some-basic-networking-concepts-simplified/#osi-layer-2-bridging-and-layer-3-routing) mode really should only be used for routers that are VPN clients, as the server will get bombarded with all the router level traffic that comes along with TAP mode, which a NAS is usually not configured to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the WINS server in the global config of the samba server of the synology to make Netbios name resolution work and then push the WINS server DHCP option with your vpn-server.

To enable WINS add these two lines to the [global] section in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
wins support=yes

name resolve order=wins lmhosts hosts bcast
```

To make your openvpn server propagate the address of the wins server add this to its configuration:

```
push "dhcp-option WINS <IP-Address of the synology device>"
```

To analyze the problem properly I suggest you use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and take a look at the Netbios queries that happen when you try to reach your synology device to access a share from your windows client by pressing Windows+R and entering `\\<SYNOLOGY HOSTNAME goes here>`.

I stumbled upon this solution in the [synology forums](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/41993?reply=164286).